# In a k8s pod with istio injected, why envoy call localhost,the packets pass PREROUTING chain

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, istio

as I know, when a process send packets, the packets should only pass iptables OUTPUT and POSTROUTING.

but when I tested in pod with istio injected. I found when envoy call localhost:xxx ,the packets truely pass PREROUTING and INPUT. why does this happend?

Comment: AFAIK istio-init init container is used to setup the iptables rules so that inbound/outbound traffic will go through the sidecar proxy, so i'm not sure why shouldn't it use prerouting and input? [There](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot#iptables-schematic) is iptables schematic which should answer your question. Additionally check this [link](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Proxy-redirection) about envoy proxy in/out bound traffic methods. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the istio iptables [script](https://github.com/istio/cni/blob/master/tools/packaging/common/istio-iptables.sh).

---

[INPUT](https://github.com/istio/cni/blob/master/tools/packaging/common/istio-iptables.sh#L651-L655) is used to drop all inbound traffic except established connections.

---

[PREROUTING](https://github.com/istio/cni/blob/master/tools/packaging/common/istio-iptables.sh#L547-L548)  is used to handle inbound ports. Traffic will be redirected to Envoy, which will process and forward to the local service. If not set, no inbound port will be intercepted by istio iptables.

According to [proxy-redirection](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Proxy-redirection) on github

> Inbound
>
> The iptable rule for inbound redirection is straightforward assuming all traffic needs to be redirected to the proxy. Additional rules are needed if inbound traffic needs to bypass the proxy, e.g. ssh.
>
> iptables -t nat -A **PREROUTING** -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port ${ISTIO_PROXY_PORT}

---

There is the whole [iptables schematic](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Understanding-IPTables-snapshot#iptables-schematic) for istio, so you might actually check what **PREROUTING** and **INPUT** exactly does.

[image]

---

Additionally there is blog on [medium](https://medium.com/faun/understanding-how-envoy-sidecar-intercept-and-route-traffic-in-istio-service-mesh-20fea2a78833) about Understanding How Envoy Sidecar Intercept and Route Traffic in Istio Service Mesh. Worth to take a look if you want to understand the whole process.

Comment: I think OP is asking about local traffic specifically. Normally, inbound traffic from outside the container would pass through PREROUTING but locally generated traffic destined to local process would not. And yet somehow it does here. Do you happen to know how?